# Formalizing arithmetic prroofs using Agda

Tags: math, agda

I am trying to proof some lemmas using agda, and to do so, I need to prove facts about natural numbers like:

- An even natural number m can be represented as 2*k where k is another natural number.
- if m^2 is even, then m is even.
- if 2 * n^2 = 4 * k^2 then n^2 = 2 * k^2 . .
- if 0 < m then 0 < m^2.

I do not know where to start to prove these facts. I am not sure if Agda has any predefined definitons that may help in that task.

Any help s highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Some imports first.

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Product
open import Data.Empty
open import Relation.Nullary
open ≡-Reasoning
open import Function
open import Algebra
open import Data.Nat.Properties
open CommutativeSemiring commutativeSemiring hiding (zero; _+_; _*_; sym; refl)
```

You can express evenness as a function or as an inductive type.
The difference is explained here: http://oxij.org/note/BrutalDepTypes/
It's introduction, so you really should read it, as well, as other introductions,
if you want to use agda. There are quite a few such texts.
Here is the definition of Even:

```
data Even : ℕ -> Set where
  ezero : Even 0
  esuc  : {n : ℕ} -> Even n -> Even (suc (suc n))
```

Then you need to define exponentiation.

```
infixr 8 _^_

_^_ : ℕ -> ℕ -> ℕ
n ^  0      = 1
n ^ (suc m) = n * n ^ m
```

But `n ^ 2` reduces to `n * (n * 1)`, which is unconvenient. So I'll be using this instead:

```
_^2 : ℕ -> ℕ
n ^2 = n * n
```

Auxiliary lemma

```
m+1+n≡1+m+n : ∀ m n → m + suc n ≡ suc (m + n)
m+1+n≡1+m+n zero    n = refl
m+1+n≡1+m+n (suc m) n = cong suc (m+1+n≡1+m+n m n)
```

Next statement reads just as your first fact.

```
as-2*k : {n : ℕ} -> Even n -> ∃ λ k -> n ≡ 2 * k
as-2*k  ezero    = 0 , refl
as-2*k (esuc en) with as-2*k en
...              | n , refl = {!!}
```

The type of the hole is `Σ ℕ (λ k → suc (suc (n + (n + 0))) ≡ k + (k + 0))`.
It's a reduced version of `∃ (λ k → suc (suc (n + (n + 0))) ≡ k + (k + 0))`.
Obviously `k` should be equal `suc n`.

```
as-2*k : {n : ℕ} -> Even n -> ∃ λ k -> n ≡ 2 * k
as-2*k  ezero    = 0 , refl
as-2*k (esuc en) with as-2*k en
...              | n , refl = suc n , {!!}
```

Now the type of the hole is `suc (suc (n + (n + 0))) ≡ suc (n + suc (n + 0))`.
So you need to skip `suc`s by `cong` and rearrange the rest of the expression by the previously defined lemma.

```
cong : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : Set b}
       (f : A → B) {x y} → x ≡ y → f x ≡ f y
cong f refl = refl

as-2*k : {n : ℕ} -> Even n -> ∃ λ k -> n ≡ 2 * k
as-2*k  ezero    = 0 , refl
as-2*k (esuc en) with as-2*k en
...              | n , refl = suc n , cong suc (sym (m+1+n≡1+m+n n (n + 0)))
```

`sym` makes `y ≡ x` from `x ≡ y`.

Another auxiliary lemma:

```
remove-*2 : (n : ℕ) -> {m : ℕ} -> Even (n + n + m) -> Even m
remove-*2  0          e = e
remove-*2 (suc n) {m} e
    with subst (λ n' -> Even (suc (n' + m))) (+-comm n (suc n)) e
... | esuc e1 = remove-*2 n e1
```

And rather dirty proof of the second fact. First you need to prove some basic cases.

```
even-sqrt : {n : ℕ} -> Even (n ^2) -> Even n
even-sqrt {0}            ezero   = ezero
even-sqrt {1}            ()
even-sqrt {suc (suc n)} (esuc e) = {!!}
```

If `n` is `1` then `n ^2` is not the inhabitant of `Even`, so you can exclude this case by `()`. The context now looks like this:

```
Goal: Even (suc (suc n))
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
e : Even (n + suc (suc (n + n * suc (suc n))))
n : ℕ
```

The proof is quite long, so I give you a link to the whole code: http://lpaste.net/101722
There is a proof for the third fact too.
The fourth fact is the simplest one:

```
0<n^2 : {n : ℕ} -> 0 < n -> 0 < n ^2
0<n^2 (s≤s le) = s≤s z≤n
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it useful to take a look how to proove (x - 1) (x ^ + 1) = x ^ 3 - 1 using ring axioms:
https://github.com/solomatov/AgdaSandbox/blob/master/Ring.agda

Answer (score 0):

Agda's standard library is fairly minimal and hard to browse through.

You might want to consider looking into `Data/Nat.agda` and `Data/Nat/*.agda` for things related to natural number arithmetics.

You will probably have to define the `even` and `odd` predicates for instance, grepping them yielded nothing. You might want to define them inductively over natural numbers, or to reuse more general notions of divisibility found in the files I mentioned.